# T-SQL : How to add data into columns stored in a string?

Tags: t-sql

I want to create a variable table in t-sql with 13 columns (YEAR || months) and store the column names into an array.
Then using a loop I want to enter data in each column.

eg:

```
for i 1..12 
insert into @tablename (@i)
```

Is it possible?
Do I need to create a cursor?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far ?

Comment: DECLARE fmth varchar(32) = 'January.February.March';
DECLARE smth varchar(32) = 'April.May.June';
DECLARE tmth varchar(32) = 'July.August.September';
DECLARE fomth varchar (32) = 'October.November.December';
DECLARE mth varchar(10);
DECLARE i tinyint = 3;
DECLARE Report TABLE
(
 Year smallint, 
 January int,
 February int,
 March int,
 April int,
 May int,
 Juni int,
 July int,
 August int,
 September int,
 October int,
 November int,
 December int
)
WHILE i > 0
BEGIN
 mth = PARSENAME(fmth,i)
 insert into Report (mth)
 i = i - 1;
END

Comment: also with @ because they are variables, but I don't have enough time to figure out how to add them

Comment: @Fili What is your expected end result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to understand your question properly, is this you are looking for?

Below code will loop three times and insert into the respective columns.

**Note**: You can not implement table variable with dynamic SQL. You have to use Physical or temporary table for that purpose.

```
DECLARE @fmth varchar(32) = 'January.February.March'; 
DECLARE @smth varchar(32) = 'April.May.June'; 
DECLARE @tmth varchar(32) = 'July.August.September'; 
DECLARE @fomth varchar (32) = 'October.November.December'; 
DECLARE @mth varchar(10); 
DECLARE @i INT =3; 

CREATE TABLE #Report  
( Year smallint, January int, February int, March int, April int, May int, June int, July int, August int, 
September int, October int, November int, December int ) 

WHILE(@I > 0)
BEGIN
     DECLARE @IChar Varchar(5) = CAST(@I AS VArchar(5))
     DECLARE @Month1 varchar(20) =   PARSENAME(@fmth,@i) 
     DECLARE @Month2 varchar(20) =   PARSENAME(@smth,@i)
     DECLARE @Month3 varchar(20) =   PARSENAME(@tmth,@i)
     DECLARE @Month4 varchar(20) =   PARSENAME(@fomth,@i)

     -- Do Insert operation here 
        DECLARE @MyDynamicSQL VARCHAR(4000) 
        = 'INSERT INTO #Report('+@Month1+','+@Month2+','+@Month3+', '+@Month4+')
            VALUES ('+@IChar+','+@IChar+','+@IChar+','+@IChar+')'
            EXEC(@MyDynamicSQL) 

     SET @i = @I - 1
END
 SELECT * FROM #Report
DROP TABLE #Report
```

Comment: I want to create a table where I can view the net purchase cost of customers. I have 3 table from where I take the data for the formulae. I have a solution, but I needed this thing in order to have a place where to insert the data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.